# Is there a visualizer/tool for developing path planners?

Tags: ros, path-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on a path planner that incorporates dynamic obstacle avoidance. I was wondering if there is a visualizer or any tool available for developing path planners?

Some of the requirements would be:

1. To visualize a 2D (or even 3D) space
2. Include static and dynamic obstacles programmatically
3. Visualize robot position and goal
4. Visualize the progress of the path planner as it searches the space (whichever path planner is used, eg: A*, RRT etc.)

Something similar to this: http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192810/is-there-a-visualizer/tool-for-developing-path-planners?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can definitely visualize all of the above using Rviz, using `nav_msgs/Path` and `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` outputs from your algorithm.

If you algorithm fits into the `move_base` state machine approach, it may be best to develop your planner as a plugin (probably for the local planner). If not, you'll probably still find reusing layered costmaps as a very helpful for sensor processing and world state.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0